# How to Learn Ruby on Rails - other than database integration (as a blog)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I am trying to learn Rails. It seems like most Rails tutorials explain how to build a blog. The problem is - I'm not building a blog. I am trying to learn how to build a Rails application that consumes data from an external API, manipulates the returned data, and displays it in a Rails View (but also uses a user registration functionality like I've seen in some blog tutorials).

Are there any tutorials or learning resources that teach Rails functionality other than building a blog? :) I would appreciate any insight on mapping out my learning process.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise you to do these assignments from Stanford's Web Applications class - 
http://www.stanford.edu/~ouster/cgi-bin/cs142-spring12/projects.php

Alternatively, you could also go through the Software Engineering for SaaS course offered by Coursera / Udacity.
https://class.coursera.org/saas/lecture/index

The official Rails guides are pretty comprehensive too - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/, you should keep them bookmarked.

Sign up and follow railscasts.com for best practices and you could try contributing to http://railsforcharity.org/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. I've looked at the http://guides.rubyonrails.org and there is some good information there. I've also watched a few railscasts. I will definitely look at the other two resources. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a good programmer, I'm only a student, and there isn't much I can really help you with. More than that, I consider C++ my main programming language, and I don't know Ruby. But i have a reference that can help you, and I wish to help you, because I know how hard it is to find where to start learning language from. Here's a link: 
http://www.softwaredeveloper.com/features/74-ruby-on-rails-resources-tutorials-050207/
Hope it'll help you a little bit.

Comment: This looks like a good resource. I'll spend some time on it. Thanks.